# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Hadoop mapreduce programme

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am getting Array index bound of exception in Map programme. Below is the data and mapreduce programme.

**Data:**

1,raja,10,10000

2,jyo,10,10000

3,tej,11,20000

4,tej1,11,20000

**MapReduce Programme:**

```
    public static class EmployMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
{
                String dNname;
                public void map(LongWritable k,Text v,Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
                    String text=v.toString();
                    String[] textArry=text.split(",");
                    System.out.println(textArry.length);
                    int dNo=Integer.parseInt(textArry[2]);
                    int sal=Integer.parseInt(textArry[3]);
                    if(dNo==10){
                        dNname="Automation";
                    }else{
                        dNname="Manual";
                    }
                    con.write(new Text(dNname), new IntWritable(sal));
                }
            }

            public static class EmployReduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{
                int totalSal;
                public void reduce(Text k, Iterable<IntWritable> v,Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
                    for(IntWritable val:v){
                        totalSal+=val.get();
                    }
                    con.write(k, new IntWritable(totalSal));
                }
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
                Configuration conf=new Configuration();
                Path input=new Path(args[0]);
                Path output=new Path(args[1]);
                Job job=Job.getInstance(conf);
                job.setJarByClass(Employ.class);
                job.setMapperClass(EmployMap.class);
                job.setReducerClass(EmployReduce.class);
                job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
                FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, input);
                FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);
                System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1);
            }

        }
```

**Error Logs**

```
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at Employ$EmployMap.map(Employ.java:21)
    at Employ$EmployMap.map(Employ.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Error is at line 21 i.e. at "int dNo=Integer.parseInt(textArry[2]);" can some one help me to understand whats wrong with the code?

Comment: It looks like you have an extra empty row in your data. Please check the output of `System.out.println(textArry.length);` before the error. Also you can add a condition in your code to check array length before access the data from particular index in array.

Answer (score 0):

Check your dataset. you are splitting the data with , and there is additional space between columns after comma remove the space between the data and run it. I hope this works.